# Count the number of data from table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn number of data in table in controller class. I was able to learn number of data in table in View class. But I couldn't apply View's code to Controller class. In controller class, in foreach loop, Model is underlying and gives an

> Error : Does not exist in current context.

View Class Code sth like that:

```
@model IEnumerable<XYZ.Models.Course>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Capacity == 1 && item.Records.Count() != 0)
    {
      ............
    }
}
```

It works(count the number of table) But in controller class how can I convert code to controller class? In controller class, in `foreach` loop, Model is underlying and give an error:

> does not exist in current context.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RecordID,SID,CID,CName")] Record record)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (item.Capacity == 1 && item.Records.Count() <= 1)
            {
                db.Records.Add(record);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            } 
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory - You have not declared a variable name `Model` in the POST method. None of your code makes any sense - you view does not even have a form. And how is `Record` related to the model in the view which is `IEnumerable<Course>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `@Model.Count()`

Comment: but @ cannot use controller class c#.It is javascript for view. O need to write in controller using c sharp

Comment: you want to count in Controller class.?

Comment: yes because I try to insert data according to capacity.If it does not exceed, it will insert to table.Therefore I am trying to count

Comment: but you are posting only one `record` from view to Controller, so you can not count, on other side you can check if `record` is null or not